# Call to undefined function curl_init() in codeiginter

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I am receiving this error when I try to access my newsletter plugin, I have uncomment the curl extension in both php\php.ini and apache\php.ini, and also in configuration file of php. Even I restarted my server after changes but still I am getting error. How can I solve this issue ??

Comment: Run your `phpinfo` and note the exact loaded configuration of your `php.ini` and do the change there and do a restart and see.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran yes I have checked curl is enabled there!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried these extensions ([extesnions link here](http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/)) according to my php version and it worked!
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Start the Curl extension of PHP directly by changing PHP.ini file or by clicking wamp and then scroll to PHP->extensions